# Accessing object in collection using helper with Meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

So I created a helper

```
user(id = false, data = 'name') {
    if(parseInt(id) === id)
        return UserDetails.findOne({'id': id})[data]; // fetch one - details
    else
        return UserDetails.find({}).fetch(); // fetch all
}
```

problem comes from the fact that some of the elements in my collection are objects

```
user_avatar : {
    url: 'avatar.png',
    size: 14.4
}
```

and I can't access those using `{{ user UserID user_avatar.url }}` is there a right way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out

Instead:

```
return UserDetails.findOne({'id': id})[data];
```

I used the `stevezhu:lodash` package and

```
return lodash.get(UserDetails.findOne({'id': id}), data);
```

now with `{{ user UserID 'user_avatar.url' }}` I get the fine result.